# Bootstrap responsive header image shrinking/disappearing

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a responsive header with different sections, headerright, headercenter, headerleft etc. with different content.

I've managed to add an image to the header but if I shrink the page or view it on a mobile browser it's either shrunk to a tiny dot of a picture or disappeared completely.

here is my HTML/CSS code: www.jsfiddle.net/9118jw4s although the preview won't help as it just displays the fullsize image.

Could someone help or link me to a tutorial on how to make the header and it's images responsive w/ bootstrap, Thanks.

Comment: I think I may have solved the problem by adding a min-width to the CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see your #header-container has padding settings that could be shrinking your image whenever re-sizing. Try this instead.

```
 #header-container {
    margin:auto;
  }
```

or

```
 #header-container {
    padding-left:15%;
    padding-right:15%;
  }
```

I also see a typo in you .headerleft= "mind-width"

Mostly I would be mindful of using pixels as padding sizes. Try percentages instead. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap has class for responsive images ".img-responsive"...

```css
.headerbox {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

#header-container {
  padding-left: 140px;
  padding-right: 140px;
}

.headerdiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  padding-left: 65px;
  padding-right: 65px;
}

.headerleft {
  height: 146px;
  min-width: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-position: center left;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header">
  <div id="header-container" class="container">
    <div class="headerdiv">
      <a href="" class="headerleft">
        <img src="http://s7.postimg.org/ixxfw8n5n/header_logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="header SUSU logo">
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I'm using bootstrap4 alpha which uses ".img-fluid" I believe. Nevertheless I have solved my problem but thanks for your help.

Comment: and in img class without "="

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a body background image.

```
 body {
      background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: contain;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover; 
       background-position: top;
       background-size: auto;           
    }
```

It will turn responsive.